# Eclipse IMarker formatting rules

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to define a new type of IMarker in Eclipse plugins such that the colorPreferenceValue can vary based on some passed in parameter? For now, I've just hardcoded in ten different marker types for ten different colors, but that's very inelegant.

Thanks